# Replacing quote marks around strings in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi, replace, surround

I have something akin to `<Foobar Name='Hello There'/>` and need to change the single quotation marks to double quotation marks. I tried `:s/\'.*\'/\"\0\"` but it ended up producing `<Foobar Name="'Hello There'"/>`. Replacing the `\0` with `\1` only produced a blank string inside the double quotes - is there some special syntax I'm missing that I need to make only the found string ("Hello There") inside the quotation marks assign to `\1`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use groupings:

```
:s/\'\(.*\)\'/\"\1\"
```

This way argument 1 (ie, \1) will correspond to whatever is delimited by \( and \).

Answer (score 77):

There's also [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697), if you're looking to do this fairly often. You'd use `cs'"` to change surrounding quotes.

Comment: is there a way to map this to some leader command? I can't get to do it :\

Comment: You shouldn't need to map this to a leader command, since it's using a custom `cs` motion with two arguments - `'` as the target, and `"` as the replacement.

Answer (score 22):

`%s/'\([^']*\)'/"\1"/g`

You will want to use `[^']*` instead of `.*` otherwise

`'apples' are 'red'` would get converted to `"apples' are 'red"`

Comment: Or use `.\{-}` instead of `.*`.  See `:help /\{-`.

Answer (score 9):

unless i'm missing something, wouldn't `s/\'/"/g` work?

Comment: That was my compromise, but I felt that it wasn't quite right, especially if there were a single quote inside the attribute. I don't think that can happen in XML, but it might happen in some other situation down the road that needs this same solution.

Comment: A single quote inside a single-quoted attribute should be `&apos;` and a double quote inside a double-quoted attribute should be `&quot;`.  Of course a single quote might live inside a double-quoted attribute and vice versa...

Answer (score 8):

Just an FYI - to replace all double quotes with single, this is the correct regexp - based on rayd09's example above

```
:%s/"\([^"]*\)"/'\1'/g
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put round brackets around the part of the expression you wish to capture.

```
s/\'\(.*\)\'/"\1"/
```

But, you might have problems with unintentional matching.  Might you be able to simply replace any single quotes with double quotes in your file?

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea -- you want to have `"\1"` as your replace clause, but you need to put the "Hello There" part in capture group 1 first (0 is the entire match). Try:

`:%/'\(.*\)'/"\1"`

Answer (score 1):

Shift + V to enter visual block mode. Highlight the lines of code you want to remove single quotes from.

Then hit : on keyboard

Then type

s/'//g

Press Enter.

Done. You win.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you want to do this on an entire file ...

N Mode:

```
ggvG$ [SHIFT+:]
```

X Mode:

```
'<,'>/'/" [RET]
```